# TYPO3: EXT:news different templateLayouts and corresponding TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news, typo3-8.x

I have configured EXT:news with different `templateLayouts` as shown in https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/TemplateSelector/Index.html

Everything works fine.

Now I want to have different TypoScript per templateLayout.
I have two different list-types: list-type 98 and list-type 99. You can choose them in flexform and the fluid-templates switches correct.

But how is it possible to have separate typoscripts for list-type 98 and one for list-type 99?

e.g. list-type 98: 5 news per page, list-type 99: 10 news per page.

Comment: I think adding the per page option in FlexForm is not that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a kind of workaround.

**1st, create the TypoScript:**

```
plugin.tx_news.settings {
 default {
  setting1 = abc
  list.image.width = 100
  detail.image.width = 123
 }
 type1 {
  setting1 = abcdef
  list.image.width = 200
 }
}
```

**2nd, adopt the templates**

Instead of the default partial

```
<f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings,iterator:iterator}" />
```

you can now do this

```
# use a f:case if more than 1 templateLayout used
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout}">
 <f:then>
  <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings.type1,iterator:iterator}" />
 <f:then>
 <f:else>
  <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings.default,iterator:iterator}" />
 </f:else>
</f:if>
```

this should now change the settings everywhere within this partial within this one action.

---

Drawbacks I currently see:

- you need to adopt every template
- I guess it would make sense to something like `plugin.tx_news.settings.default < plugin.tx_news.settings` to have all default settings available as well.